# Format output from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

From reading the BeautifulSoup documentation I have managed to write a short python script to scrape a table and print it however I can't figure out how to format it into a table. The end goal is to get football game predictions from the website: https://afootballreport.com/predictions/over-1.5-goals/ and to save them to a text file.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup("https://afootballreport.com/predictions/over-1.5-goals/")
for record in soup.findAll('tr'):

    for data in record.findAll('td'):

     print(data.text.strip())
```

and this is the output:

```
03/28
17:30
Iceland Reykjavik Youth Cup


Fjölnir / Vængir U19
Valur / KH U19
Over 1.5
Valur / KH U19 have over 1.5 goals in 100% of their games in the last 2 months (total games 6).
03/28
17:30
Saudi Arabia Pro League


Al Ittifaq
Al Quadisiya
Over 1.5
Al Ittifaq have over 1.5 goals in 100% of their games in the last 2 months (total games 8).
```

I want to have it so it has a column for each row: Date, Time, Football League, Hometeam, AwayTeam, Tip, Description.
Like this:

```
Date, Time, Football League, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, Tip, Description
03/28, 17:30, Iceland Reykjavik Youth Cup, Fjölnir / Vængir U19, Valur / KH U19, Over 1.5, Valur / KH U19 have over 1.5 goals in 100% of their games in the last 2 months (total games 6).
```

Would someone be able to help me please?

Comment: Have a look into pprint. "Pretty printer" as i like to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing an awful lot of work. Whenever I see a `<table>` tag, I'd first try pandas' `.read_html()`. It'ss do most of the work for you and then you can just manipulate the dataframe as needed.

```
import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html('https://afootballreport.com/predictions/over-1.5-goals/')
table = tables[0]

table[['Date', 'Time']] = table['Home team - Away team'].str.split('  ', expand=True)
table = table.drop(['Home team - Away team'],axis=1)
table =  table.rename(columns={"Unnamed: 3":"Description"})   


table[['Football League', 'Home Team', 'Away Team']] = table['Tip'].str.split('  ', expand=True)
table = table.drop(['Tip'],axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
print (table.head(5).to_string())
      Logic                                        Description   Date   Time              Football League             Home Team       Away Team
0  Over 1.5  Valur / KH U19 have over 1.5 goals in 100% of ...  03/28  17:30  Iceland Reykjavik Youth Cup  Fjölnir / Vængir U19  Valur / KH U19
1  Over 1.5  Al Ittifaq have over 1.5 goals in 100% of thei...  03/28  17:30      Saudi Arabia Pro League            Al Ittifaq    Al Quadisiya
2  Over 1.5  Sarreguemines have over 1.5 goals in 100% of t...  03/28  19:00            France National 3         Sarreguemines   Strasbourg II
3  Over 1.5  Mons Calpe have over 1.5 goals in 100% of thei...  03/28  19:29   Gibraltar Premier Division            Mons Calpe   Glacis United
4  Over 1.5  Glacis United have over 1.5 goals in 100% of t...  03/28  19:29   Gibraltar Premier Division            Mons Calpe   Glacis United
```

**EDIT:**

If you are using Pandas Version 0.24.2

```
import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html('https://afootballreport.com/predictions/over-1.5-goals/')
table = tables[0]

table[['Date', 'Time']] = table['Home team - Away team'].str.split('  ', expand=True)
table = table.drop(['Home team - Away team'],axis=1)
table =  table.rename(columns={"Logic":"Description"})   


table[['Football League', 'Home Team', 'Away Team']] = table['Home team - Away team.1'].str.split('  ', expand=True)
table = table.drop(['Home team - Away team.1'],axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, looks alot easier. However, the home team and away team column isn't showing? if it was showing that it would be perfect

Comment: oh ya. I didn't notice that. I'll see If I can fix that

Comment: actually it is there, just offset. I'll print it off to show you in an edit above

Comment: if you give me a few minutes, I'll fix the table to correctly have the data as you want

Comment: ah great thanks, how do I then name the rename the columns to Date, Time, Football League, Hometeam, AwayTeam, Tip, Logic? I would like to be able to use the data in another script so have to be able to search by hometeam and awayteam for example

Comment: I have a line that can rename coloumns above. Like I said, the league and team name is little tricky. Not impossible, but I'll need to sit down and code it out, but literally about to leave for the night in a minute. I can get to that tomorrow, or might be a good way for you to practice with pandas on your own.

Comment: actually, nevermind. Was able to split it. Just make sure I got the home team and away team right. If they're switched, just switch it at: `table[['Football League', 'Home Team', 'Away Team']] = `

Comment: and if this worked out for you, make sure to accept the answer

Comment: Thanks for looking in to this for me, I understand that you are going out now but I am getting the error shown here: https://pastebin.com/XvMCjygx  --- i will try and fix it myself

Comment: Oh that’s odd considering it worked for me. What version of python and pandas you running?

Comment: I should be home in a few hours. I’ll see if I can quickly boot up then an give it a run.

Comment: Name: pandas
Version: 0.24.2
Python 3.7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190873/discussion-between-oli-shingfield-and-chitown88).